# How to parse a string with raw escape sequences?

Tags: c++, string

Suppose there are 2 strings:

```
string parse(const string& s) {
    // how to write this function?
}

int main() {
    string s1 = R"(hello\n\"this is a string with escape sequences\"\n)";
    string s2 = "hello\n\"this is a string with escape sequences\"\n";
    assert(parse(s1) == s2);
}
```

My question is, how to write the function `parse()` in order to make the assertion succeed, other than some hand-made code traversing the string and checking against every possible escape sequence?  Is there any existing idiom for doing this?

Comment: you need to list all the rules of parsing to facilitate writing  parse() function.

Comment: raw sequences or no, the parsing algorithms are the same.

Comment: @gman the rules are just the same as those of c++ string literal escape sequences

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It's probably the easiest to just implement the replacement of escape sequences using a regular expression, but if you insist on doing it without, you can always write the string to a file as part of a valid C++ program that prints the string to a file, then read it from the file.
(This can also be improved to work without temp files at all)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <assert.h>

using std::string;

string parse(const string& s) {
    std::ofstream ftmp("tmpsrc.cpp");
    ftmp << "#include <iostream>\nint main(int argc, char* argv[]){\n";
    ftmp << "  std::cout << \"" << s << "\";\nreturn 0;}\n\n";
    ftmp.close();
    system("g++ -o tmpprint tmpsrc.cpp");
    system("./tmpprint > tmpstr.txt");
    std::ifstream fin("tmpstr.txt",std::ios::in|std::ios::binary);
    fin.seekg(0,std::ios::end);
    int size=fin.tellg();
    fin.seekg(0);
    string res;
    res.resize(size);
    fin.read(&res[0],size);
    fin.close();
    // Add delete of temp files here
    return res;
}

int main() {
    string s1 = R"(hello\n\"this is a string with escape sequences\"\n)";
    string s2 = "hello\n\"this is a string with escape sequences\"\n";
    assert(parse(s1) == s2);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for giving out the complete program.  Intricate as it is, it does work.  I'll take this as an answer if no other better solution comes up.  Thanks again.

Comment: Ok.. And if I use MSVC or CLang ?

Comment: You can do it with either, only the compiler command details change.  With MSVC you might have a PATH issue as well.

Comment: This is such a terrible answer.  Non-portable, slower, insecure, and the unaccepted answers are better.

Comment: If you read the question and answer carefully, you would see that OP specifically asked about an option without code that checks for escapes.   All answers, including this 'terrible' one indicate that it's best to do the checking, but this answer includes a solution that solves under these restrictions even though it may not be practical.  Other answers do not.

Answer (score 1):

You could use string stream. Check each character of the string for an escaped backslash '\' character. When found, check for the next character to be a valid escape character. Then write a string to the string stream for that escape character sequence.

```
std::string parse(const std::string& s)
{
    std::stringstream  ss{""};

    for(size_t i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        if (s.at(i) == '\\')
        {
            switch(s.at(i + 1))
            {
                case 'n':  ss << "\n"; i++; break;
                case '"':  ss << "\""; i++; break;
                default:   ss << "\\";      break;
            }       
        }
        else 
        {
            ss << s.at(i);
        }
    }

    return ss.str();
}
```

Comment: As you are already range checking, is operator [] better in this case?
A sidenote, is std::stringstream better than just appending to a string?

`std::string output{s.capacity()};`  and then `output += "\n"` etc...

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, C++ escape sequencies are very easy to replace them manually

```
string string_replace( const string & s, const string & findS, const std::string & replaceS )
{
    string result = s;
    auto pos = s.find( findS );
    if ( pos == string::npos ) {
        return result;
    }
    result.replace( pos, findS.length(), replaceS );
    return string_replace( result, findS, replaceS );
}

string parse(const string& s) {
    static vector< pair< string, string > > patterns = {
        { "\\\\" , "\\" },
        { "\\n", "\n" },
        { "\\r", "\r" },
        { "\\t", "\t" },
        { "\\\"", "\"" }
    };
    string result = s;
    for ( const auto & p : patterns ) {
        result = string_replace( result, p.first, p.second );
    }
    return result;
}

int main() {
    string s1 = R"(hello\n\"this is a string with escape sequences\"\n)";
    string s2 = "hello\n\"this is a string with escape sequences\"\n";
    cout << parse(s1) << endl;
    cout << ( parse(s1) == s2 ) << endl;
}
```

Output:

> hello "this is a string with escape sequences"
>
> 1

http://ideone.com/jMAfRK

Comment: Supporting the full set of escape sequences should be a bit complicated: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape