# How to parse escape sequences using c++?

Tags: c++

I have a file with strings: "\x55\u1111 some text\n".
I saw the same question here: [How to parse a string with raw escape sequences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27617903/how-to-parse-a-string-with-raw-escape-sequences) but the solution can't be used in a real application.
How to parse this string in c++?

Comment: Why the solution to the other question "can't be used in a real application" ?? I had a quick look and I don't see what should be wrong with it...

Comment: The [PEGTL](https://github.com/ColinH/PEGTL) contains an example that does just what you need, you'll find it in `examples/unescape.cc`.

Comment: What are you converting to? Do you want wchar_t?

Comment: wchar_t would be nice or just utf8. PEGTL is good but I don't want to use additional library only for one function also I have boost with phoenix.